# keep suggestion box always directly under textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text input with a suggestion box which appears under the input when something is typed. The problem is when the page is zoomed sometimes the box appears in a slightly diferent position (1-3 pixels). Is there a way to garantee, no matter what the page scale is, that the suggestion box will always remain exactly 0px left and 0px top relative to the bottom line of input field? Thanks.

```
tBox = $('#textBox')[0];

$('#suggestionBox').css({
    width: "151px",
    border: "1px solid grey",
    position: "absolute",
    top: (tBox.offsetTop + tBox.offsetHeight) + "px",
    left: tBox.offsetLeft + "px"
});

<input type="text" id="textBox" />
<div id="suggestionBox" style="display:none;">suggesion</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using this http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Position?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpFm9/1/

```
$("#suggestionBox").position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "left bottom",
    of: $('#textBox')
});
```

Comment: It wasn't my issue. Just commenting on the +1 :)

Comment: You are not understanding me. I didn't ask the question. Look at the OP, it isn't me. I am merely saying thanks for that snippet as it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

see the simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/JQeTT/

```
$('#suggestionBox').css({
   width: "151px",
   border: "1px solid grey",
   position: "absolute",
   top: ($('#textBox').offsetTop + $('#textBox').offsetHeight) + "px",
   left: $('#textBox').offsetLeft + "px"
});

$('#textBox').focus(function(){

   $("#suggestionBox").show();
}).blur(function(){ //if lost the focus, the suggestion box hide again
   $("#suggestionBox").hide();
});
```

Comment: Not even aligned without zooming.